# Python 3 unicode annoyances

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode

I have a string, created from a list. When I try to send the string as the body of an email, I get this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 1242: ordinal not in range(128)

This is the "en" character, or dash, taken from a web page.

So I tried to use this code to fix the issue:

```
    message = str(all_items)
    message.replace('\u2013','-')
```

Problem is, that does not work. Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: We don't know. You forgot to show the code you're using to compose the email.

Comment: Can you show how does the string is being created?

Comment: The string is a dictionary of extracts from a web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean to replace string inplace?

[`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) does not change the string inplace, but returns the replaced string.

You need to assign the result of `str.replace` back:

```
message = message.replace('\u2013', '-')
```